# Observing mouse event in ViewModel Swift (Reactive Cocoa 3.0)

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm trying to make a connection between my view and my viewModel using RAC 3.0. (Been reading Colin Eberhardt great [tutorials on this](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/05/15/mvvm-reactive-cocoa-3.html)) I want to subscribe to a Signal that fires every time `func mouseUp(theEvent: NSEvent)` is called. I.e.

```
func mouseUp(theEvent:NSEvent){
  //create some signal or pass a variable here to my viewModel
}
```

and then in my viewModel I would like to subscribe to that stream.

```
let signalFromview = MutableProperty<String>("")

signalFromView.observe(next: { println($0) })
```

But I can't get this to work. The only way I've managed to get this to work is to subscribe to a SignalProducer like so:

View:

```
func mouseUp(theEvent:NSEvent){
    viewModel.signalFromView.put(someValue)
}
```

ViewModel:

```
signalFromView.producer
|>start { println($0) }
```

But this isn't what I want since using the producer 'pulls' the value, i.e. upon first running this the code in the viewModel will be run on initialization with an empty value since it's trying to pull something that isn't there...

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MutableProperty`s should be used more like properties, and not as a proxy to a signal. So it should be initialized with a sensible initial value so that anyone that observes it via the `producer` will get values that make sense.

If you want a `Signal`, you can set up the signal with something like this:

```
let (signal, sink) = Signal<String, NoError>.pipe()
```

In your mouseUp function, you'd send events using something like:

```
sendNext(sink, someValue)
```

And you'd observe using:

```
signal.observe(next: { println($0) })
```

Comment: But how do I observe this in my view model, which is a different class from my view? How do I make that connection?

Comment: I'm just showing some examples on how to use the `sink`/`signal` combo that `pipe()` vends. You will expose and access them as properties as needed on your classes. So in your case, I would actually let the view own a signal that vends the events, and the view model would `map` it to your string representation, and expose a signal of that.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I appreciate your input, and It all makes sense. What I can't figure out though, is as I said before how to make the connection between the two classes so my viewModel can listen to that signal instantiated in my view

Comment: If you have a view controller between the two, then that would act as the glue. The view would expose the event signal, and the view model would expose an observer (sink) that takes events. The VC would do `signal.observe(vm.sink)` to hook them up, and the VM would observe the signal associated with the exposed sink.